# Android Device Monitor starting with error from intellij on Mac

Tags: android, macos, intellij-idea

When trying to start the **Android Device Monitor** from Intellij (or Android Studio) on Mac the result is an error message dialog telling

```
Failed to create the Java Virtual Machine.
```

When calling .../android-sdk-macosx/tools/monitor (which is actually called from the menue in intellij) the error message gets more specific to

```
Error: could not find libjava.dylib
Failed to GetJREPath()
```

What have to be done to enable the monitor to be callable from within Intellij?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To solve the problem you have to do two things:

1. Find or install a JRE/JDK which contains the library libjava.dylib, e.g. in **/Library/Internet Plug-Ins/JavaAppletPlugin.plugin/Contents/Home/lib**
2. enable the monitor app to use java from the JRE near the lib from 1.) e.g. **/Library/Internet Plug-Ins/JavaAppletPlugin.plugin/Contents/Home/bin**

To resolve the first problem you can can install a JRE as decribed [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/webnotes/install/mac/mac-jre.html)

To resolve the second problem you have to set the path to the "java" interpreter from 1.) in the file **.../android-sdk-macosx/tools/lib/monitor-x86_64/monitor.app/Contents/Info.plist** (for 64bit)

like

```
<array>
        <string>-vm</string><string>/Library/Internet Plug-Ins/JavaAppletPlugin.plugin/Contents/Home/bin/java</string>
        <!-- to use a specific Java version (instead of the platform's default) uncomment one of the following options:
            <string>-vm</string><string>/System/Library/Frameworks/JavaVM.framework/Versions/1.4.2/Commands/java</string>
            <string>-vm</string><string>/System/Library/Frameworks/JavaVM.framework/Versions/1.5.0/Commands/java</string>
        -->
        <string>-keyring</string><string>~/.eclipse_keyring</string>
        <string>-showlocation</string>
        <!-- WARNING:
            If you try to add a single VM argument (-vmargs) here,
            *all* vmargs specified in eclipse.ini will be ignored.
            We recommend to add all arguments in eclipse.ini
         -->
</array>
```

The monitor app then should be able to create a JVM and to run.